# Is there any way of simplifying this if statement?

Tags: python

```
if g < 20 and f >= 90 and c == "Change".lower() and e != "Operate".lower() and t == "Yes".lower():
        print("Go to the next part")
```

(This is after asking a couple of questions using input).. Can I assign them to a variable and then print?

I am pretty new at programming.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, `"Change".lower()` would be much more simply written as `"change"`, for example.  Are you sure that it's these string literals you want to convert to lower case, and not the string entered by the user?

Comment: Did you mean `if g < 20 and f >= 90 and c.lower() == "change" and e.lower() != "operate" and t.lower() == "yes":`? If so, that's about a simple as it gets.

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I assign them to a variable and then print?"? What's "them"? And then print what?

Answer (score 4):

Since all of the conditions are connected by `and`, one way to simply this would be to use `all` builtin and pass a tuple of conditions.

```py
>>> if all((<cond1>, <cond2>, <cond3>,...<condn>)):
        < if block >
```

So, the code you have written will change to:

```py
if all((g < 20, f >= 90, c == "Change".lower(), e != "Operate".lower(), t == "Yes".lower())):
        print("Go to the next part")
```

If all the conditions are connected by `and`, then `all` can be used, or if all the conditions are connected by `or`, then `any` can be used; however, if some conditions are connected by `and`, and some are connected by `or`, then a combination of `all`, and `any` will be required.

On a side note, calling `lower()` on a value like `"Change".lower()` is useless and you can directly use `"change"`, but it'd have been useful if you were calling it on a variable like `c.lower()`

Comment: Can you add OP's conditions so that the answer matches the question?

Comment: If it is connected by the `Or` operator, which keyword do you have to use?

Comment: @PCM, `any` can be used in that case.

Comment: But I think that's why `and` is a better choice. Any mix of and and or will fail.

Comment: @tdelaney, yeah I totally agree with you, but since OP specifically asked about simplifying above condition, I used `all`. This is readable only if all the conditions are connected by `and` (`all` can be used), or if all the conditions are connected by `or` (`any` can be used). However, if the some conditions are connected by `and`, and some are connected by `or`, then using multiple `all`, and `any` might not be so preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant in the `lower()` methods to lower the input:

```
c.lower() == "change"
```

One option can be to create a `dataclass` that holds all input values, and add a method to check if it's valid

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Input:
    g: int
    f: int
    c: str
    e: str
    t: str

    def is_valid():
        return all(g < 20, f >= 90, c.lower() == "change", e.lower() == "operate", t.lower() == "yes")
```

and the usage is:

```
inp = Input(<input params>)
if inp.is_valid():
    print("go to next part")
```

This way the code is readable, and the validation function is encapsulated, so it might be also easier to maintain.

Regarding the assignment to a variable, you can assign the condition `bool` value result to a variable and check it:

```
x = inp.is_valid()
if x:
    print("go to next part")
```